# How can I adjust my text input to my screen sizes, and fix position?

Tags: html, css, responsive

first of all I'm new here. I hope I can continue to move forward in accordance with the rules.

First of all, I explain what I want to do: I have text inputs in the picture I showed you below. I want to change their position as I show them in the picture. But when I change positions, their positions disappear on different screen sizes. How can I fix this?

image

[image: 1]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/65vmaykc/

```css
body {font-family: sans-serif;}
p {color: #666;}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #e74c3c;  
}
.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 98em) {
    .centered {
        max-width: 98em;
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Header styles minus menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.masthead {
    background: #e74c3c;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
}

.site-title {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 44.44em) {
    .site-title {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
    
@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    .site-title {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
}

.site-title a {
    color: hsl(5, 45%, 95%);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.site-title a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Card Based Layout - Base styles */
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.site-title {
    color: white;
}

.card {
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 2em; 
}

.card a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
}

.card-content {
    padding: 1.4em;
}

.card-content h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.card-content p {
    font-size: 95%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Flexbox styles */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {  
  .cards {
    margin-top: -1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .card {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 0.5em);
    /* width: calc(50% - 1em); */
  }
} /* mq 40em*/

@media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
  .cards {
    margin-top: inherit;
  }
  
  .card {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 0.5em);
    /* width: calc(33% - 1em); */
  }
} /* mq 60em*/
```

```html
  <div class="centered">

    <div class="site-branding">
      <h1 class="site-title">Flexbox - Card Layout</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- .site-title -->
  </div>
  <!-- .centered -->
</header>
<!-- .masthead -->

<main class="main-area">

  <div class="centered">

    <section class="cards">

      <article class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <figure class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/f2dlr8i.png" alt="meow">
          </figure>
<div id="wrapper">

            <div class="form-group" id="agrup" > <input type="number"id="asecenegi" ></div>

 


 <div class="form-group"> <input type="number"id="bsecenegi"></div>
    <div class="form-group"> <input type="number"id="csecenegi"  > </div>

  <div class="form-group"><input type="text" value="Kalınlık:" id="kalinlik" ></div>
  
  <div class="form-group"><input type="text" value="Sonuç:" id="sonuc" ></div>
  
 <div class="form-group"> <span  id="wins"></span></div>
 

</div>
          <!-- .card-content  SOL KISIM-->
        </a>
      </article>
      <!-- .card -->

      <article class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <figure class="thumbnail">
           
          </figure>
<form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div cellpadding="0"class="responsive" cellspacing="0" style="float:left; margin:0 0 0 80px" class="row"">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        
          <div class="panel-body">
           
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <div class="form-group">
           
              <p style="color:black;"> <b>Saçın A Ölçüsü</b></p>
              
        
              
             
              <input type="number"
                     name="number1"
                     class="form-control"
                     class="second"
                    
                     id="productname" />
            </div>
            
            <script>

$('#productname').keyup(function (){
    $('#asecenegi').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});

$('#asecenegi').keyup(function (){
    $('#productname').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});


</script>

            
            
            <div class="form-group">
 <p style="color:black;"> <b>Saçın B Ölçüsü</b></p>
              <input type="number"
              name = "number2"
                     class="form-control"
                     value="6/11/2015"
                     id="introdate" />
            </div>
            
                <script>

$('#introdate').keyup(function (){
    $('#bsecenegi').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});

$('#bsecenegi').keyup(function (){
    $('#introdate').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});


</script>
            
            
            
            <div class="form-group">
 <p style="color:black;"> <b>Et Kalınlığı</b></p>
              <input type="number"
                     class="form-control"
                     
                     id="url" />
            </div>
            
                    <script>

$('#url').keyup(function (){
    $('#csecenegi').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});

$('#csecenegi').keyup(function (){
    $('#url').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});


</script>   
            

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("url2").value = e.target.value
}
</script>

<select name="" onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option>Materyal Seçimi Yapınız                         Yoğunluk</option>
    <option value="7.86">Demir                                                      7.86</option>
    <option value="8">Dkp Saç                                                  8</option>
    <option value="7.95">Paslanmaz Çelik                                     7.95</option>
    <option value="8.96">Bakır                                                       8.96</option>
    <option value="8.55">Pirinç                                                        8.55</option>
    
    
    <option value="7.2">Döküm Çelik                                           7.2</option>
    <option value="2.72">Alüminyum                                              2.72</option>
    <option value="2.72">6061 Alüminyum (AlMg1SiCu)               2.72</option>
    <option value="2.8">7005 Alüminyum (AlZn4,5Mg1,5Mn)      2.8</option>
    <option value="2.8">7020 Alüminyum (AlZn4,5Mg1)              2.8</option>
    
    
    
    <option value="8.8">Bronz                                                      8.8</option>
    <option value="7.28">Teneke                                                    7.28</option>
    <option value="7.1">Krom                                                       7.1</option>
    <option value="19.36">Altın                                                        19.36</option>
    <option value="10.5">Gümüş                                                    10.5</option>
    
    <option value="13.6">Cıva                                                        13.6</option>
    <option value="22.6">İridyum                                                    22.6</option>
    <option value="21.45">Platin                                                       21.45</option>
    <option value="19.22">Tungsten                                                 19.22</option>
    <option value="18.9">Uranyum                                                 18.9</option>
    
    
    <option value="11.37">Kurşun                                                    11.37</option>
    <option value="8.75">Kobalt                                                      8.75</option>
    <option value="8.64">Kadmiyum                                               8.64</option>
    <option value="8.3">Nikrom                                                     8.3</option>
    <option value="7.7">Alüminyum Bronzu                                  7.7</option>
    
    <option value="7.42">Manganez                                               7.42</option>
    <option value="7.3">Kalay                                                       7.3</option>
    <option value="7.1">Çinko                                                       7.1</option>
    <option value="6.69">Antimon                                                   6.69</option>
    <option value="5.91">Galyum                                                    5.91</option>
    
    <option value="4.6">Titanyum                                                  4.6</option>
    <option value="3.6">Baryum                                                    3.6</option>
    <option value="2.8">Skandüyum                                              2.8</option>
    <option value="2.8">Duralümin                                                 2.8</option>
    <option value="2.73">Alüminyum folyo                                       2.73</option>
    
    <option value="2.25">Teflon                                                        2.25</option>
    <option value="2.1">Beton                                                        2.1</option>
    <option value="2.1">Grafit                                                         2.1</option>
    <option value="1.8">Paronit                                                      1.8</option>
    <option value="1.74">Magnezyum                                               1.74</option>
    
    <option value="1.74">Nikel                                                          1.74</option>
    <option value="1.7">Karbon                                                       1.7</option>
    <option value="1.54">Kalsiyum                                                    1.54</option>
    <option value="1.42">Delrin                                                         1.42</option>
    <option value="2.8">Polioksimetilen                                          1.41</option>
    
    
    <option value="1.4">Fiber                                                            1.4</option>
    <option value="1.35">Poliasetal - pom                                         1.35</option>
    <option value="1.35">Tekstolit                                                      1.35</option>
    <option value="1.2">Kestamid                                                    1.2</option>
    <option value="1.2">Poliyamid                                                   1.2</option>
    
    <option value="1.2">Polietilen                                                     1.2</option>
    <option value="1.2">Poliemit                                                      1.2</option>
    <option value="1.15">Kaprolon (PA 6)                                          1.15</option>
    <option value="0.96">Alpolen                                                       0.96</option>

    

        
    
</select>

         
            <div class="form-group">
 <p style="color:black;"> <b>Materyal</b></p>
              <input type="number" step="0.01"
                     class="form-control"
                    
                     id="url2" />
            </div>
         

         </div>
         

         <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button type="button" id="updateButton"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        onclick="productUpdate();">
                  Hesapla
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 
 
 
</form>
          <!-- .card-content -->
        </a>
      </article>
      <!-- .card -->

      <article class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <figure class="thumbnail">
         
          </figure>
           <table  id="productTable" 
       
             class="card"  class="table table-bordered table-condensed panel panel-primary">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sacın A Ölçüsü</th>
              <th>Sacın B Ölçüsü</th>
              <th>Et Kalınlığı</th>
              <th>Materyal</th>
              <th>Sil</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
          <!-- .card-content -->
        </a>
      </article>
      <!-- .card -->
      
      
        <script>
    function productUpdate() {
      if ($("#productname").val() != null &&
          $("#productname").val() != '') {
        // Add product to Table
        productAddToTable();
      hesapla();
        // Clear form fields
        formClear();

        // Focus to product name field
        $("#productname").focus();
      }
 
    }
    
    
    function hesapla()
{
    var a=Number(document.getElementById("productname").value); // a ölçüsü
    var b=document.getElementById("introdate").value; // b ölçüsü
    var m=document.getElementById("url").value; // et kalınlığı 
    var n=document.getElementById("url2").value; // materyal
     
     var z = a * b / 100 * (m / 100) * (n / 100);
    
    
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = z.toFixed(2);
    
    
    
    
    
}
    
    

    // Add product to <table>
    function productAddToTable() {
      // First check if a <tbody> tag exists, add one if not
      if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
        $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
      }

      // Append product to the table
      $("#productTable tbody").append(
          "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + $("#productname").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $("#introdate").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $("#url").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $("#url2").val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" +
              "<button type='button' " +
                      "onclick='productDelete(this);' " +
                      "class='btn btn-default'>" +
                      "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' />" +
              "</button>" +
            "</td>" +
          "</tr>"
          );
    }

    // Clear form fields
    function formClear() {
      $("#productname").val("");
      $("#introdate").val("");
      $("#url").val("");
    }

    // Delete product from <table>
    function productDelete(ctl) {
      $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
    }
  </script>

      
      <!-- .card -->

    </section>
    <!-- .cards -->

  </div>
  <!-- .centered -->

</main>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Read [ask]: post your code _in your question_. You can use [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the look of your website according to screen size, the CSS @media rule is your friend.
W3Schools reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  input{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

For example: The code above will reduce the width of an input field when you look at it on a screen with a width less than 768px. You can play around with this function and adjust the size to your liking.

And adjusting the position is easy as well. All you need to know about is the CSS position property.
W3Schools reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But when I set the location as in the link you shared above. It goes to different locations on different screen sizes. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really get the issue here.
Oh the JSFiddle link you shared, everything seems to be working fine